# Clipboard sync between Win/Mac/iPhone devices?

Tags: windows, macos, iphone, sync, clipboard

Is there a solution out there for syncing clipboard items between Win/OSX/iPhone devices? [Pastebot](http://tapbots.com/pastebot/) and [Syncopy](http://www.syncode.com.au/apps/syncopy/) come close, but both lack Windows support.

Comment: might want to look at https://pastefire.com/index.html, but it doesn't sync clipboards.

Answer (score 1):

Try [myPhoneDesktop](http://www.myphonedesktop.com/).  Clients for Mac, Windows, Linux, Web, and an iPhone App.

Answer (score 0):

[Skip](http://www.skiptheapp.com/) is the only app that I have found that does this (two way syncing clipboard) almost like a hot box for sharing between all your clients. Actually it took me an hour of Google searches and several app purchases before I found it.

Where most apps fail, skip has

- Windows program
- Two way syncing
- Works on all platforms
- Drag and drop file sharing